# Why is Array.isArray always returning false here?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to cast form data to a custom type, but I'm having trouble getting it to recognize an array in the custom type. I saw this method begin used in another similar problem, but it isn't working for me. Is there another way of doing this?

I need to detect the array type as using `value as string` splits the string character by character instead of putting the string to the first index. I can't use `.push()` either, because it doesn't know if `object[key]` is an array or not.

Simplified version of the custom type:

```
export type CustomType = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    items: string[];
    [key: string]: (string | string[] | number)
}
```

Here is the code:

```
const form = document.getElementById("form") as HTMLFormElement;
const data = new FormData(form);

const object = {} as CustomType;
data.forEach((value, key)=> {
    if(Array.isArray(object[key])) {                 // <---- Always false
        const arr = value.toString().split(",");
        object[key] = arr;
    }
    else {
        object[key] = value as string;
    }
});
```

Comment: _"The `Array.isArray()` method determines whether the passed value is an `Array`."_ - `object[key]` will never be an array (what a `console.log(object[key])` would have told you). So it's working as expected.

Comment: As a side-note, what is the point of `const arr = value.toString().split(",");`? Is just a VERY roundabout and VERY error prone way to convert an array of data to array of strings? If so, there are better way to do that. If not, then...it just seems like a mistake.